# Using foreach to satisfy two requirements C#

Tags: c#, foreach

I'm having a crack at solving something in C# and would like some guidance on an issue I'm experiencing. I have list of field sizes that I need to extract the entry with the both the largest X and the smallest Y. I'm currently using the following snippet, I'm desiring to return the value in yellow below of 50 and use it as an entry further down in my code, but the code is giving me the value in red which matches a value of 85. Is it possible to run a foreach twice to satisfy the desired outcome?

```
double totalX = property.Width1 + property.Width2;
double totalY = property.Length1 + property.Length2;

if (!(totalX > largestX && totalY <= smallestY))
    largestX = totalX;
    smallestY = totalY;
```

[image]

I've used the following code snippet to satisfy my requirement, unsuccessfully.

```
double totalX = property.Width1 + property.Width2;
double totalY = property.Length1 + property.Length2;

if (!(totalX > largestX && totalY <= smallestY))
    largestX = totalX;
    smallestY = totalY;
```

Comment: You're not using a single foreach in your code example

Comment: Regardless if this is the issue or not, use `if (condition) {  instruction1; instruction2; }`, not `if (condition) instruction1; instruction2;`, . In the second case, "`instructions2`" is always executed, even if the condition is false.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why the 50 entry has both the "the largest X and the smallest Y".  The X is clearly the biggest value in that column, but the Y value is not.  Why is that row, then, selected?

Comment: @Idle_Mind perhaps it would make more sense to go with the largest X regardless and see if it achieves the desired result...when I think about it, it does ultimately contravene my priority

Comment: If you want a GOOD answer, we need to see what kind of structure `property` is, and how you are using a `foreach`. There is probably a quick, easy way to do it, but we don't know what you're actually working with...

Comment: @Idle_Mind the structure of the property is in essence what's seen in the image. The code adds X1 and X2, returns the largest and the field number should be stored for use later in the code. Perhaps I need a keypair value to be able to find the maximum total X and the associated field value i.e. 8.35 is the max XTotal, and store Field 50 for use later in the code

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided a comprehensive code example, I'm making some assumptions. But you could have something like this?

```
double? smallestY, largestX = null;

foreach(var property in properties)
{
    double totalX = property.Width1 + property.Width2;
    double totalY = property.Length1 + property.Length2;

    if(smallestY is null || smallestY > totalY)
        smallestY = totalY;

    if(largestX is null || largestX < totalX)
        largestX = totalX;
}
```

Also, keep in mind that **C# is not space/tab sensitive**. When you omit the bracket on a statement, it considers just the first line to be part of that statement.

So, when you write:

```
if (!(totalX > largestX && totalY <= smallestY))
    largestX = totalX;
    smallestY = totalY;
```

It is the same as writing

```
if (!(totalX > largestX && totalY <= smallestY))
{
    largestX = totalX;
}
smallestY = totalY;
```

That is, the last line is executed regardless of the condition.